# Properties of Martingales

Tags: martingales

I found following problems about properties of martingales and I would like to know is my approach correct for first problem and how to exactly solve second one.

Problem is following: Let $\{Y_n\}_{n\ge 0}$ be a martingale w.r.t. the filtration $\{F_n\}_{n\ge 0}$ and let $E(Y_n^2)<\infty$ $\forall$ n. Show that for arbitrary $i\le j\le k$, 
\begin{equation*}
E((Y_k-Y_j)Y_i)=0
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
E[(Y_k-Y_j)^2|F_i]=E(Y_k^2|F_i)-E(Y_j^2|F_i).
\end{equation*}

What I did with first one:
\begin{align*}
E((Y_k-Y_j)Y_i)&=E(Y_k\cdot Y_i-Y_j\cdot Y_i)\\
&=E(Y_k\cdot Y_i)-E(Y_j\cdot Y_i)\\
&=E[E(Y_k\cdot Y_i)|F_i]-E[E(Y_j\cdot Y_i)|F_i]\\
&=E[Y_i\cdot E(Y_k|F_i)]-E[Y_i\cdot E(Y_j|F_i)]\\
&=E[Y_i\cdot E(Y_k)]-E[Y_i\cdot E(Y_j)]\\
&=E[Y_i\cdot 0]-E[Y_i\cdot 0]= 0
\end{align*}

With second one I started like this:
\begin{align*}
E[(Y_k-Y_j)^2|F_i]&=E[(Y_k^2-2Y_kY_j-Y_j^2)|F_i]\\
&=E[(Y_k^2|F_i)]-2E[(Y_kY_j|F_i)]-E[(Y_j^2|F_i)]=\\
&=\dots
\end{align*}

I have trouble showing following steps. I'm not sure that steps so far are correct ones. I hope someone helps me with those proofs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first one the last two steps are wrong. You wrote $E(Y_k|F_i)=EY_k$. But $E(Y_k|F_i)=Y_i$ by martingale property. So you get $EY_i^{2}-EY_i^{2}=0$.

Now $E(Y_k-Y_j)^{2}|F_i)=E(Y_k^{2}|F_i)+E(Y_j^{2}|F_i)-2E(Y_kY_j|F_i)$. Write the last term as $-2 E(E(Y_kY_j|F_j|F_i))$. Then observe that $E(Y_kY_j|F_j)=Y_jE(Y_k|F_j)=Y_j^{2}$ by martingale property again. Now I hope you can finish the proof.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So For last one I get now $E(Y_k^2|F_i)+E(Y_j^2|F_i)-2E(Y_j^2|F_i)=E(Y_k^2|F_i)-E(Y_j^2|F_i)$ as required.